# Comparing Strings in a while loop

Tags: java, string, while-loop

Okay so I need to ask the user to enter yes or no and then validate. I have to do this in a while loop. All of it compiles, I did not include the imports etc here. Here is what I have,

```
String str;
str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter answer, yes or no?");

while(!str.equals("yes")||!str.equals("no")) 
{
   str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Invalid entry. Please enter yes or no.");

}
```

When I compile, it shows me the dialog to enter a string. If I enter `yes` it tells me invalid, if i enter `no` it tells me invalid. If I take the `||!str.equals("no")` out it works fine but with only if I enter `yes`. So anyone can help me? Thanks..

Comment: Say your condition out loud.

Comment: Lets change data types a little from String to int. Do you know any `x` where sentence `x!=1 OR x!=2` would be false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any non-null 'str'

```
 while(!str.equals("yes")||!str.equals("no"))
```

will always be true.
 Instead make it `while(!str.equals("yes") && !str.equals("no"))`

Answer (score 0):

**make it**

```
while (!str.equals("yes") && !str.equals("no")) {
   str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Invalid entry. Please enter yes or no.");
}
```